# SQL - Selecting rows based on date difference

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose we have below table:

| Code | Dt |
| --- | --- |
| c1 | 2020-10-01 |
| c1 | 2020-10-05 |
| c1 | 2020-10-09 |
| c1 | 2020-10-10 |
| c1 | 2020-10-20 |
| c2 | 2020-10-07 |
| c2 | 2020-10-09 |
| c2 | 2020-10-15 |
| c2 | 2020-10-16 |
| c2 | 2020-10-20 |
| c2 | 2020-10-24 |

Combination of Code and Dt is unique. Rows are sorted based on Code and Dt. Database is Oracle 12.
For every code, I want to get list of its Dts that each Dt is grater than 7 days compared to previously selected Dt. Therefore, result should be:

| Code | Dt |
| --- | --- |
| c1 | 2020-10-01 |
| c1 | 2020-10-09 |
| c1 | 2020-10-20 |
| c2 | 2020-10-07 |
| c2 | 2020-10-15 |
| c2 | 2020-10-24 |

I've tried self join based on row_number() to join every row with its previous row if date difference is grater than 7. But there is a challenge that each row should be compared with previously selected row  and not its previous row in table. Any solutions? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can solve this relatively easily using [match_recognize](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DWHSG/pattern.htm#DWHSG8956)

```
with data(code, dt) as (
  select 'c1',  to_date('2020-10-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') from dual union all
  select 'c1',  to_date('2020-10-05', 'YYYY-MM-DD') from dual union all
  select 'c1',  to_date('2020-10-09', 'YYYY-MM-DD') from dual union all
  select 'c1',  to_date('2020-10-10', 'YYYY-MM-DD') from dual union all
  select 'c1',  to_date('2020-10-20', 'YYYY-MM-DD') from dual union all
  select 'c2',  to_date('2020-10-07', 'YYYY-MM-DD') from dual union all
  select 'c2',  to_date('2020-10-09', 'YYYY-MM-DD') from dual union all
  select 'c2',  to_date('2020-10-15', 'YYYY-MM-DD') from dual union all
  select 'c2',  to_date('2020-10-16', 'YYYY-MM-DD') from dual union all
  select 'c2',  to_date('2020-10-20', 'YYYY-MM-DD') from dual union all
  select 'c2',  to_date('2020-10-24', 'YYYY-MM-DD') from dual
)
select *
from data match_recognize (
  partition by code
  order by dt
  measures
   init.dt dt
  one row per match
  pattern (init less_than_7_days*)
  define
    less_than_7_days as less_than_7_days.dt - init.dt < 7
)
```

You just partition by code, order by dates and then get any row `init` and 0-many following rows (`less_than_7_days*`) that have date difference less than 7 (compared with init). You return 1 row for this whole match (init + following rows) that will contain date from `init`

Comment: Wow, that looks amazingly easy. I always shied away from `match_recognize` in spite of sensing how powerful it is. But seeing now how simple and readable your solution is, I'll sure give it a try and read up on it.

Comment: Two remarks: **1.** You don't have to convert strings to get a date. You can just use date literals, e.g. `date '2020-10-01'` instead of `to_date('2020-10-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')`. **2**. If the OP wants the rows ordered, they should add `order by code, dt` at the end of the query.

Comment: I need to use `to_date` as my date format mask from nls is different ;)

Comment: No, `DATE '2020-10-01'` is an ANSI date literal. It is no string that must be converted. NLS settings don't matter, because there is nothing to convert. See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm#BABGIGCJ

Comment: Many thanks @Petr. Code was super quick on a large table

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a case for a hierahical query.
Compute pairs and traverse the chain

```
with pairs(Code, Dt, dtnext) as (
  select t1.Code, t1.dt, Min(t2.dt)
  from tbl t1
  join tbl t2 on t1.code=t2.code and t2.dt >= t1.dt + INTERVAL '7' DAY
  group by t1.Code, t1.dt
),
h(Code, Dtn) as (
  select Code,  Min(dt)
  from tbl
  group by Code
  union all
  select h.Code, p.dtnext
  from h
  join pairs p on p.code=h.code and p.Dt= h.dtn
  )
select * 
from h
order by code, dtn
```

[The fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=4bd6d956f02bfe5e421d3f0ff44723f3)

Returns

```
CODE    DTN
c1  01-OCT-20
c1  09-OCT-20
c1  20-OCT-20
c2  07-OCT-20
c2  15-OCT-20
c2  24-OCT-20
```

Comment: Many thanks @Serg, you solution worked perfectly but I chose another solution since it was very fast on my large table.